# Implementing "AddToCard" in React.js ecommerce project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, shopping-cart, react-context

[image][image]I have been building an e-commerce website. I have an issue after adding items to the shopping card. I successfully add the items to the card but the problem is when I click on "Continue Shopping" button I am navigating to the products page however products are not displaying properly as before.

I attached the pictures: When I clicked on cart button , a modal opens, when I click on "continue shopping" I get other screen and I get this error in the console:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `product` of type `array` supplied to `Product`, expected `object`.
    in Product (at ProductList.js:42)
    in div (at ProductList.js:38)
    in div (at ProductList.js:34)
    in section (at ProductList.js:33)
    in ProductList (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:20)
    in Switch (at App.js:19)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:11)
    in ProductProvider (at src/index.js:10)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1375
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See /react-warning-keys for more information.
    in div (at ProductList.js:38)
    in div (at ProductList.js:34)
    in section (at ProductList.js:33)
    in ProductList (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:20)
    in Switch (at App.js:19)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:11)
    in ProductProvider (at src/index.js:10)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1375
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See react-warning-keys for more information.
    in div (at ProductList.js:38)
    in div (at ProductList.js:34)
    in section (at ProductList.js:33)
    in ProductList (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:22)
    in Switch (at App.js:19)
    in App (at src/index.js:12)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:11)
    in ProductProvider (at src/index.js:10)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1375
```

I could not find any related question or project online. This is my first big React project and I hope I will find solution here.

Context.js

```
getItem = id => {
    const product = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);
    return product;
 };
addToCart = id => {
const tempProducts = [...this.state.products];
const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
const product = tempProducts[index];
product.inCart = true;
product.count = 1;
const price = product.price;
product.total = price;
this.setState(
  () => {
    return {
      products: [tempProducts],
      cart: [...this.state.cart, product],
      detailProduct: { ...product }
    };
  },
  () => this.addTotals()
);
};
```

I believe the issue is choosing the item and modifying in the "addToCart" method. I know that If I need to modify an item in the list,I have to specifically find its index too, otherwise items are not going to display correctly as it is now.

Comment: the errors, you posted are clear you've supplied an array instead of an object to `Product` component and the others wants you to add a key to each component in a loop.

Comment: others have their keys.                     return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
and product is already object

Comment: error logs also says in Route (at App.js:20) and
    in Switch (at App.js:19) need  to have key